# Handle blur event of parent element fired by focus on child element and by clicking outside of child

Tags: javascript, jquery, onblur, event-bubbling, onfocus

I have a "parent div" containing a child box input `type=number`. When user clicks outside of input box I use `blur` or `focusout` event of parent div to use input values at some other place.

I also need to use `$('inputbox').trigger('focus')` at some place, which fires "parent div"'s blur event unwantedly and runs code on that event.

Please give a solution to stop this parent blur event on child's focus OR give a way to find whether focus is made by trigger('focus') on child element or by user clicking outside of parent div.

I need to fire parent Blur only when user clicks outside of it & not when focus is triggered through code.

Comment: can you share a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Please see final answer.

Answer (score 3):

This worked perfect for me:

```
if (e.relatedTarget === null) ...
```

Answer (score 2):

with jquery you can make custom events  very easily , something like:

```
$('inputbox').trigger('special-focus');
```

then you can wait for this event just like any other event:

```
$('div').on('special-focus' , function(){ ... } );
```

this will prevent your events from interfering with the built in ones.

I guess if you don't want to use that suggestion then do this in your click handler or your focus handler of the child

```
 .on('focus' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
   /// the rest of your code ...
 });
```

this will stop the propagation of events to parent elements

Comment: thanks but still if I have to use .focus() to focus on input box and it is firing blur of parent .

Comment: edited answer , added another solution that will work for you

Comment: you can attach to the click event , you might half to play with where to catch the event .

Comment: Thanks Scott...I have posted the solution as answer.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was checking the `relatedTarget` property of the `eventObject` object in the handler function.

```
$("#parentDiv").focusout(function (eventObject) {
    if (eventObject.relatedTarget.id === "childInputId")
        /// childInput is getting focus
    else
        /// childInput is not getting focus
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`.on('blur',...)` of parent fires **before** `.on('focus' ,...)` of child. 
Anyways for a parent div containing child input box
  we can use 
 `$('input').trigger('special-focus');`
and then

```
  $("#form" ).on('special-focus', '.parentdiv' , function(event) {
          $("#form" ).off('blur', '.parentdiv');
          $(event.target).focus();
          $("#form" ).on('blur', '.parentdiv' , showValuesOnBlur);
     });
```

Now blur of parent will not fire on focus of child.
This worked for me. i.e. off & on the blur event of parent inside special-focus.
Thanks Scott Selby :)

Comment: If you're not going to select my answer as the correct answer , then you may want to consider provider a complete answer of what you did to get this code working .   Someone else visiting this page would not unserstand just throwing in  a custom event there and not showing how it was triggered

Comment: .on('focus' , function(e){    e.stopPropagation(); etc will not work here as parent blur fires first.. also working code contains on and off of blur event
that's why I didn't mark your answer corrent mate but still it was useful to suggest custom events by you.Had I marked this correct ,developer would keep on trying  e.stopPropagation(); which does not work here.

Comment: I got that , that is fine , I just meant to write a complete answer ,and I wasn't telling you you had to either , I'm not the Stackoverflow boss, I was just saying you should consider.  By complete I didn't mean mine was correct I just meant to fill in the parts you left out

Comment: okay mate, also your answer gave a strong direction to work on. appreciable.